# ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTEGER" LINE 2: v_stage INTEGER:=0;

Tags: postgresql, string-matching, fuzzy-search

```
DECLARE
  v_stage INTEGER:=0;
[...]
  RETURN QUERY 
  SELECT 1.0::FLOAT, v_stage, sex, birthdate, place, district, subdistrict, village, race,
     complexion, eyecolor, haircolor, height, weight, hp, mother, father, picture, sidenote,
     mannerism, name, method, crimetype, suspect_id
  FROM public.suspect
  WHERE complexion = p_complexion TEXT,
  AND CASE WHEN p_eyecolor IS NOT NULL THEN eyecolor = p_eyecolor ELSE true END
  AND CASE WHEN p_haircolor IS NOT NULL THEN haircolor = p_haircolor ELSE true END
  AND CASE WHEN p_height FLOAT IS NOT NULL THEN height = p_height ELSE true END
  AND CASE WHEN p_weight FLOAT IS NOT NULL THEN weight = p_weight ELSE true END
  AND CASE WHEN p_sex IS NOT NULL THEN sex = p_sex ELSE true END
  AND CASE WHEN p_sidenote TEXT IS NOT NULL THEN sidenote = p_sidenote ELSE true END
  AND CASE WHEN p_mannerism TEXT IS NOT NULL THEN mannerism = p_mannerism ELSE true END
  AND CASE WHEN p_method TEXT IS NOT NULL THEN method = p_method ELSE true END
  AND CASE WHEN p_crimetype TEXT IS NOT NULL THEN crimetype = p_crimetype ELSE true END;
[...]
```

---

->ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTEGER" "ALWAYS GOT THIS ERROR! I DON'T KNOW WHY"
->LINE 2:   v_stage INTEGER:=0;

Please for someone who can fix this, I really appreciate...

Update with code from comment:

```
DO 
$$ 
    DECLARE 
    v_stage INTEGER:=0; 
    RAISE NOTICE 'y'; 
    RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT 
            1.0::FLOAT, v_stage, sex, birthdate, place, district, subdistrict, village, race, complexion, eyecolor, haircolor, height, weight, hp, mother, father, picture 
    FROM 
        public.suspect
    WHERE 
        complexion = p_complexion TEXT, 
    AND 
        CASE WHEN 
            p_eyecolor IS NOT NULL 
        THEN    
            eyecolor = p_eyecolor 
        ELSE 
            true 
        END 
    AND 
        CASE WHEN 
            p_haircolor IS NOT NULL 
        THEN 
            haircolor = p_haircolor 
        ELSE 
            true 
        END; 
    END$$;
```

After I added DO $$ before DECLARE then another error came: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 6: RETURN QUERY

> > > CONTEXT:  invalid type name "QUERY SELECT 1.0::FLOAT"

Comment: A `do` block can not return anything, so `return query` is wrong to begin with. But I see no reason for PL/pgSQL at all. Just run that select statement. But you are missing a `BEGIN` to make that valid PL/pgSQL. `complexion = p_complexion TEXT,` is also invalid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Well this works:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    v_stage INTEGER:=0;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'test';

END$$;

NOTICE:  test
DO
```

So I'm going to say it is something before the `DECLARE`. Add the beginning part of the function to your code example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did as you said, however, there is another error coming out: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 5: [...] then I tried to delete [...] then again error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 6: RETURN QUERY 
               ^
CONTEXT:  invalid type name "QUERY 
  SELECT 1.0::FLOAT"

Comment: DO $$
DECLARE
v_stage INTEGER:=0;
RAISE NOTICE 'y';
RETURN QUERY 
SELECT 1.0::FLOAT, v_stage, sex, birthdate, place, district, subdistrict, village, race, complexion, eyecolor, haircolor, height, weight, hp, mother, father, picture FROM public.crime WHERE complexion = p_complexion TEXT,
AND CASE WHEN p_eyecolor IS NOT NULL THEN eyecolor = p_eyecolor ELSE true END
AND CASE WHEN p_haircolor IS NOT NULL THEN haircolor = p_haircolor ELSE true END;
END$$; After I added DO $$ before DECLARE then another error came:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 6: RETURN QUERY @AdrianKlaver

Comment: I added the above to the question where it should be and formatted it so it is readable.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? Why it says error near "RETURN QUERY SELECT 1.0:: FLOAT " Please help me to solve it...

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) for how plpgsql functions need to be structured. I would also run the query outside the function as it has issues.